# Create Query SQL Injection free while getting all the content of table

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am getting all the content from the table using following queries

```
SqlCmd.CommandText = "Select * from Product";
SqlCmd.connection = myConnection();
myConnection.open();
reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
```

As far I know when we use input parameters in select then there is possible attack of SQL injection. So how do we secure when we are not using where clause.

Can we prevent SQL injection using following query.

```
SqlCmd.CommandText = "Select Name from Product";
```

Comment: No, merely adding a WHERE clause does nothing in and of itself. You risk SQL injection when you don't parameterize your user inputs.

Comment: @CodeCaster I am not passing any inputs to this query so question is this safe or not

Comment: @ZafarAli it's not safe ... as user can pass string e.g `; truncate table product` and it will be executed after your select .. user don't need `where` condition to accomplish sql injection

Comment: @Veljko89 so how do make it safe as we are not passing in parameters . We just need complete data from table

Comment: @ZafarAli A query that you are executing won't make `easier` or `harder` for SQL injection (most of the time), this is how i see it `sql injection can happen when you pass direct user input to sql command, ether from text box value or URL`, in this case, if you are loading all data `onPageLoad` you dont have to worry about injection, also it is a good practice to try keep your query inside stored procedures ... others, please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @Veljko80 that makes sense but one of my friend told that this query can sql injection, so I am looking for way as you are seeing this is not easy to to inject nor harder mean there is some threat so I want to remove that threat too

Answer (score 0):

Injection occurs when placing variables in a query that user's can put code into. Users overwrite your statements and use their own (injection of SQL code). Your select query does not meet that criteria since users cant interact with it.

There should be some functions in ASP.net that allow you to premake statements. I don't use asp.net but a google search should help you know that your in the right direction.

Comment: That mean my query is safe as I am not getting any input to call this

Comment: Safe is always relative, but yes its fine. For other queries, use premade statments